# What's the correct usage of 'it goes to show how much...' and 'it goes to how much'?

Tags: phrases

So far I've heard people saying 'it goes to show how much' as a way to use the extent of something to describe another. But then I've also come across 'it goes to how much' and I wonder if there are any differences between them.

For example:

- My dad used to scold me a lot but it goes to show how much he cared about me.
- My dad used to scold me a lot but it goes to how much he cared about me.

Comment: Please add sources, linked and attributed. ELU looks at established, attested usages; anecdotal evidence may be to mistaken usages (or may be inaccurate).

Comment: I agree with @EdwinAshworth. Your second example looks like a mistake to me, but one thing I've learned on this site is that a lot of (what I call) mistakes are quite normal in some versions of the English language.

Comment: Oh, is that so? I'll try to remember that when I encounter something like this again. As for the sources, unfortunately I couldn't seem to find it again.

Comment: I've heard *it goes to* in American courtroom dramas, only: "Objection, Your Honor. Relevance?" "It goes to credibility!" In other words, *it aims at, it addresses*.